# Bootstrap flickering active class nav links on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been working on a Bootstrap 3 page which scrolls using scrollspy and a jquery plugin. I have an unfortunate flickering issue when the page is scrolling to the desired link.

Edit: it was partially solved by the lovely lady below i.e. I had been stupid in some markup. however the flickering problem remains.

I have a fiddle that Illustrates the current problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tokolosh/kqx10g4L/1/)

here is is the scrolling javascript

```
$(function() {
$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

Its odd and I have no idea what is causing it (still a student)

Anyone else experience this? would be great to know how you overcame it

Thanks in advance

Comment: One or another of your scripts interferes with bootstrap's nav, if you don't use bootstrap's nav, then it works fine. Why don't you try something that does work with a script that is bug free? http://startbootstrap.com/templates/freelancer/

Comment: unfortunately though I used a template from that same website. Also the custom javascript used in that template has other functions within it that will break my site... i just tested it :(

Comment: The reason why it flickers is because you don't include intro in your nav you include something that that's not in the page in the nav #page-top, see http://jsfiddle.net/Tokolosh/kqx10g4L/, your code is really messy and the order of bootstrap should come BEFORE custom css and there's no way to tell what the image size is so breaking text can't be fixed. This is a rather messy way of doing this, start cleaner. You don't need page-scroll. http://jsbin.com/viyaw/1

Comment: Actually youre right I had neglected to change that section from an earlier section. Thank you, I feel a fool.... now it flickers as it passes though the section but there is probably no way of stopping that. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Tokolosh/kqx10g4L/1/) If you would like to post that response as an answer i'll happily check it as answered.... extra brownie points if you know how to get rid of the other flickering as it goes down the page :D Thank you so much

Comment: Also can you please tell me what you mean by this "the order of bootstrap should come BEFORE custom css and there's no way to tell what the image size is so breaking text can't be fixed." sorry im trying to teach myself web development and im pretty new :/

Comment: Bootstrap comes first then your css. You always load framework first, then in another style sheet, your own css. There is no image in your jsfiddle. You have to post full content for the problem you're having including the images.

Comment: Thank you it was just just to make the fiddle easier to read in case it was the CSS. it is correct in the actual code. And the image is not the problem.

Comment: I have edited the question to be more about the current flickering please dont answer the question as hopefully some other kind person can help. Thank you very much though. All the best :D